# Can't resolve all parameters for BypassSanitizerPipe: (?)

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I upgraded to Angular 8 and after updating everything I found this error on browser

**Here pipe code**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'bypassSanitizer'
})
export class BypassSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
        if (html) {
            return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
        } else {
            return '...';
        }
    }
}
```

**And here pipe module code**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BypassSanitizerPipe } from './bypass-sanitizer.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BypassSanitizerPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        BypassSanitizerPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [
        BypassSanitizerPipe
    ]
})
export class CorePipeModule {

    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: CorePipeModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

Before upgrade to 8, everything works well.
My old version is Angular 7 
[image] 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the relevant lines of `main.ts` please.  This is usually due to misconfigured DI or something similar.

Comment: Please provide the code of your pipe

Comment: Usually this error is because you has not include in the **declarations** of your module the Pipe: `declarations: [ AppComponent, BypassSanitizePipe,...]`

Comment: @Eliseo I added pipe file

Comment: I want to say that be sure that in the file `your-module.ts` you add in "declarations"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just removing the provider from pipe module to be

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BypassSanitizerPipe } from './bypass-sanitizer.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BypassSanitizerPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [
        BypassSanitizerPipe
    ]
})
export class CorePipeModule {

    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: CorePipeModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```